# Tesseract not detecting letters

Tags: python, tesseract

I'm trying to OCR this picture:

[image: this picture]

using Python Tesseract(pytesseract) but all I don't get any output except for a blank line, which i think means that it did not detect any letter.

The code I am using is this:

```
name = pytesseract.image_to_string(imo, lang='eng', config='--psm 13')
```

I am using python 3.6.5 and tesseract 4.0.0-beta.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: add white border to the image then pass it to tesseract and see the outcome

Comment: I just tried but now it gives A's as an output

Comment: binarized it before sending to teseract... use otsu

Comment: reverse? as I have already binarized it before

Comment: step 1- add white border
step 2 - binarization
step 3 - tesseract
remove config='--psm 13' and use tesseract default config and check once

Comment: nope, same results

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177606/discussion-between-nazar-khan-and-durjoy).

Comment: can you check in your command line 'tesseract $image $outbase -psm 10'

Comment: could you edit the answer of yours with the comment so I can mark this as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps should be

step 1 - Add extra white border to the image

step 2 - Binarised it using otsu or other method to get the best possible binarization

step 3 - Then send it to tesseract with psm 10 (for single character)